# Bundle external JavaScript(from a cdn) into a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What options are there to bundle an external javascript sdk into a React Component?

I have tried including the javascript in the index.html and referring to it through window.xyz . It works well but I can't do a production build since the javascript is not packaged in this way.

Is there a way to simply import a javascript file into the React Component definition?

PS: React Newbie here !

Comment: I have tried searching this (ovbiously) on internet and stackoverflow in particular but have not found a well received answer to this, hence posting it as a fresh question.

Comment: What is the library in particular you want to use ?

Comment: @asynts .js file in a .jsx file

Answer (score 6):

## If you want the script to be bundled in the build, you have 2 options:

**1. If the external file is a [module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export), I would approach it as follows**:

1. Download the external JS file and save it somewhere in the project. For example, save it to `/utils` folder.
2. Just reference it and use it in the components: `import { test } from '/utils/external'`

**2. If it's not a module**:

1. The same as above - save the file to your project.
2. The difference is that you have to configure your module bundler to export the globals. This process is called *Shimming* and [here's how to do it with Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/#global-exports).
3. The same as step 2 - `import { test } from '/utils/external'`

* *In both scenarios I assume it's a standalone external file, not being hosted somewhere as a package (npm / bower / etc.). If it's a package, instead of downloading it manually, you should use a package manager.*

---

## If you want to load it async (but not bundled):

Follow the [@Paras answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52863340/4312466), where he suggests for using a library for script async lazy loading.

Comment: OP's question is to load from CDN. Your answer assumes that the module is saved in `utils/external`. That may not always work as any updates in the CDN would not reflect automatically in the code

Comment: Also, the benefit of the CDN cannot be availed in terms of response time and caching. Also, it may not necessarily be an NPM/Bower package as you suggest in your footnote

Comment: Hey @Paras. I didn't know about your approach. It looks like a good way of resolving the case. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe it won't met the requirement the file to be packaged.

Answer (score 2):

To load external scripts from a CDN, a good option is to use the [`react-async-script-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-async-script-loader) library. Not only can it load external JS files asynchronously, but it also loads `on demand`, i.e., lazy loading and supports both parallel and sequential loading.

It allows you to decorate your component using an HOC like so:

```
export default scriptLoader(
  [
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/somelibrary1.min.js',
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/somelibrary2.min.js'
  ]
)(YourComponent)
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually you should know about the entire approach then see the codes.

You must make a separate folder for your alternative cdn `JavaScript` files which they are out of files that `webpack` build them. Then paste these files into this folder and after all import them as `externals` into `webpack` configuration.

Then config them as vendor files, and absolutely output file name should make dynamically, so the `webpack` build its bundle and then copy your `JavaScript` files into dist folder. follow below:

```
// webpack.configuration.js
~~~
module.exports = {
    ~~~
    externals: {
        cdnFileOne: `${srcRoot}/outFiles/cdnFile1.js`,
        cdnFileTwo: `${srcRoot}/outFiles/cdnFile2.js`,
    },
    ~~~
};
```

Sounds good, now you have external names for `JavaScript` files and import it into `webpack` configuration as a `externals` config.

Now you should put them in `entry` to import them as separate files:

```
// webpack.configuration.js
~~~
module.exports = {
    ~~~
    entry: {
        cdnFiles: ['cdnFileOne', 'cdnFileTwo'], <-- cdn files
        app: `${srcRoot}/app/index.js`, // <-- its your own codes
    },
    output: {
        path: '/dist',
        filename: '[name].js' // <== dynamically make your JavaScript files,
                              //      so, in dist folder you can see app.js and
                              //      cdnFiles.js file
    }
    ~~~
};
```

Surly, you must add bundles to your `HTML` template:

```
  ~~~
  res.status(200).send(`
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        ${styles}
        ${title}
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root">${ssrHTML}</div>
        <script src="app.js" defer></script>
        <script src="cdnFiles.js" defer></script>
      </body>
    </html>
 `);
~~~
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
componentDidMount () {
   const script = document.createElement("script");    

   script.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/somelibrary1.min.js";
   script.async = true;

   document.body.appendChild(script2);
 }
```

Comment: There are a few problems with this approach: 1) the component may render before the script is loaded. This may be a big issue if the component depends on variables/functionality provided by the script, 2) if 2 or more components need the scripts, this will create 1 script tag for each such component

Comment: You should be loaded in your main app file ex: app.js componentWillMount()  u can define ur all routes and all or index.html file.

Comment: In that case the script will be added in the app regardless of whether there is a component that wants to use it. Also the first issue from my comments will not be resolved by this

Comment: show ur file so better understand find better solution