# How to load external file for bundled react project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

It is possible to load data from external file when for bundled react project?

For example I have project that need some values

```
 config: {
   size: x,
   color: y
 }
```

And I have project that uses it's config

When I bundled that project and want to load file with that store config and load it. It is possible to do?

The one solution that I know is to save config into global object `window`

[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52757426/bundle-external-javascriptfrom-a-cdn-into-a-react-component) answers your question?

Comment: @MarcS. No, it is different